# Ionic Adding viewport-fit=cover doesn’t load App, only white screen

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, ios11

I'm using Ionic 3, testing on iOS 11 and iOS 10.

I’ve followed the instructions noted in this post below, adding "viewport-fit=cover" to my meta in index.html. After building my app and running it on my iOS 11 iPhone, XCode doesn’t show any errors, just a white screen. When running in the browser, all works well and no errors as well. Also on my older iPhone running iOS 10 it works fine (as before).

https://blog.ionic.io/ios-11-checklist/4

Does anyone know what’s wrong? Many thanks!

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue! Any news on that?

Comment: @lec00q nothing yet unfortunately....

Comment: I have actually found out today that using WKWebView in place of UIWebView is fixing the issue for me, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

```
<meta content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
```

I've run this in the browser, on an iOS 11 simulator and an actual iOS 11 device without any apparent issues.

Are you sure you haven't made a silly mistake, like forget the comma or something along those lines?  :-)

Comment: Interesting.  Are you 100% sure there isn't an unrelated JavaScript error preventing the app from launching?  Generally if I get The White Screen (TM), it means JS has puked during app initialization.

Comment: Pretty sure (99,9999999%) that there isn't any JS errors, are it's running OK on olde iOS and in the browser. And when I remove just these few words of code viewport-fit=cover, all works fine (with the white line at the top though)

Comment: Since you're working with iOS 11, am I correct in assuming you've already upgraded to the latest version of Xcode?

Comment: Yes, otherwise I wouldn't be able to load the App onto the iPhone running iOS 11 from anything but Xcode 9 (latest version)

Comment: Huh.  Well, I'm not sure I can be of much help at this point.  I've used this same code in two different applications with no problems.  Clearly there's an issue of some kind, but it's outside of my current realm of experience.